# Apache server 404 rewrite with existing rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I already have one `RewriteRule` implemented for all the urls which is something like this:-

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^/$   /test/$1 [L,PT]

This one is working fine.

Now I want to rewrite another rule so that incase my first rewrite throws 404 error, it could rewrite my url to my 404 page.

I checked that if I remove this existing rewriterule, then

> **ErrorDocument 404 /test/404**

works fine but doesn't work with this rewrite url

is it possible to write to two `RewriteRule`s together?